# Email template issue - Table overstretched

Tags: css, html-table, css-float, html-email

I have an email template I created but I can't seem to figure out what is stretching out the table, I've attached a screenshot for reference. Any help would be wonderful.

Here's the code for that part of the template:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:27px;height:53px;display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
        <img src="#" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:31px;height:53px;display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">    <a href="http://youtu.be" target="_blank"><img src="#" /></a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:24px;height:53px;display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /></a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25px;height:53px;display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /></a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:518px;height:53px;display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
        <img src="#" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="display:block;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
        <img src="#" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image: email template issue]

Comment: floats in emails are a no go in my experience, and why would you try to float a table cell in the first place?

Comment: Looking at this, I agree with PeterVR.  Floating table cells?  That's very non-standard and likely to cause weird rendering issues.

Comment: I've made alot of email templates, and from my experience I can safely say you SHOULD NOT use floats in emails, or tables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of float, use the html `align="left"` in your table cells. You don't need `display:block;` in the table cells, instead put it in your image tags.

Also, remove all the css width and height in your table cells and replace it with the html `width=""` and `height=""`

Also, if you put this in your table tag: `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`, you don't need the padding and margin in your table cell css.

Basic example of all combined:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="31" height="53" align="left">
      <a href=""><img  alt="" src="" width="31" height="53" border="0" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note - align left is default, so it is not really needed.